# Where can I find org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException with gradle?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.main', name: 'jenkins-core', version: '2.76'
    compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow', name: 'workflow-step-api', version: '2.13'
    compile 'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.14'
    compile 'org.connectbot.jbcrypt:jbcrypt:1.0.0'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I run "gradle build" I get the following error:

```
> Task :compileGroovy FAILED
startup failed:
/home/user/myproject/SomeClass.groovy: 26: unable to resolve class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException 
@ line 26, column 11.
        } catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException flowInterruptedException) {
            ^
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

It's as if it does not see "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException" but I added workflow-step-api and it should find it.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

The `'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.13'` dependency has a POM that has this in it (taken from [here](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/workflow/workflow-step-api/2.13/workflow-step-api-2.13.pom)):

```xml
<packaging>hpi</packaging>
```

The dependency that Gradle retrieves is the `hpi` artifact, not the `jar` one when you point at this dependency. This can be shown with a task like the following:

```groovy
tasks.create('showDependencies') {
  doFirst {
    final config = configurations.getByName(sourceSets.getByName('main').compileClasspathConfigurationName)
    config.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.findAll { it.moduleVersion.id.group.contains('jenkins') }.each {
      println("Resolved dependency: id=${it.id}, extension=${it.extension}, classifier=${it.classifier}")
    }
  }
}
```

The output:

```
 > Task :showDependencies
Resolved dependency: id=jenkins-core.jar (org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:2.76), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=workflow-step-api.hpi (org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.13), extension=hpi, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=cli.jar (org.jenkins-ci.main:cli:2.76), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=trilead-ssh2.jar (org.jenkins-ci:trilead-ssh2:build-217-jenkins-11), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=icon-set.jar (org.jenkins-ci.plugins.icon-shim:icon-set:1.0.5), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=remoting.jar (org.jenkins-ci.main:remoting:3.11), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=version-number.jar (org.jenkins-ci:version-number:1.4), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=crypto-util.jar (org.jenkins-ci:crypto-util:1.1), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=bytecode-compatibility-transformer.jar (org.jenkins-ci:bytecode-compatibility-transformer:1.8), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=structs.hpi (org.jenkins-ci.plugins:structs:1.5), extension=hpi, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=symbol-annotation.jar (org.jenkins-ci:symbol-annotation:1.5), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=annotation-indexer.jar (org.jenkins-ci:annotation-indexer:1.12), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=task-reactor.jar (org.jenkins-ci:task-reactor:1.4), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=commons-jelly.jar (org.jenkins-ci:commons-jelly:1.1-jenkins-20120928), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=commons-jexl.jar (org.jenkins-ci:commons-jexl:1.1-jenkins-20111212), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=memory-monitor.jar (org.jenkins-ci:memory-monitor:1.9), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=jmdns.jar (org.jenkins-ci:jmdns:3.4.0-jenkins-3), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=constant-pool-scanner.jar (org.jenkins-ci:constant-pool-scanner:1.2), extension=jar, classifier=null
Resolved dependency: id=dom4j.jar (org.jenkins-ci.dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1-jenkins-4), extension=jar, classifier=null
```

There are several ways to use Gradle's [dependency management features](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) to better handle dependencies. One possible way to change the dependency would be to add an [artifact dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#artifact(org.gradle.api.Action)) with the extension. This may not solve your exact use case depending on how you want your dependencies to end up, but can hopefully point you in a direction:

```groovy
compile(group: 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow', name: 'workflow-step-api', version: '2.13') {
  artifact {
    name = 'workflow-step-api'
    type = 'jar'
  }
}
```

As a side note, in the Jenkins plugin ecosystem, the [Jenkins Maven HPI Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-hpi-plugin) and [Jenkins Plugin Parent POM](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-pom) work together to do dependency management so you don't run into issues like this.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to change my gradle file as you recomend and here is what I get
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/u9t0z5DWFGZvxwZSOCSL6w
for the second option basically I need to switch from Gradle to Maven and build the project as a maven project, right?

Comment: here is the gradle file https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/deePstR7apizJ1maj5bZFQ

Comment: You don't _have_ to switch to Maven. Gradle is a much better tool than Maven in a ton of ways, but the Jenkins ecosystem is built on top of Maven. Any issues you run into with Gradle (like this one) you have to figure out yourself because there isn't a large Jenkins community around Gradle (yet). I'll take another look at my snippet today to make sure I gave you the right syntax.

Comment: @ddreian I think the last edit _should_ (fingers crossed) setup the correct dependencies (at least for your current problem).

Comment: thank you for your help! your info pointed me to the right direction but for some reason, the fix you proposed did not work. I posted an answer with my fix. Thank you again for taking the time to look into my issue.

Comment: When you ask gradle to give you the jar for the jenkins plugin, does it give you the jars for any dependenies of the first plugin (or the hpi)?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently I needed to add ext jar. Here is my build file

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public'
    }

}
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.main', name: 'jenkins-core', version: '2.76'
    compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow', name: 'workflow-step-api', version: '2.13', ext: 'jar'
    compile 'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.14'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.8'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: One thing to note, is that I don't think (not 100% sure) that `ext` will bring in all of the transitive dependencies of the `workflow-step-api`.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, in "short format" of gradle, you need to append @jar at the end: 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.13@jar'